# use custom application class in native module android library

Tags: android, react-native, android-library

I have created an android native module and trying to call some method of this module after bridging with react native module.

RN World:

```
NativeModle.ModuleName.someMethod()
```

Android world:

```
@ReactMethod
fun someMethod(){
  context.startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.class,context));
}
```

But in my android native module i have a CustomApplication class which provide necessary things to function other class like some FileProvider , SharedPreferenceProvide etc. While calling Mainactivity the code in Mainactivity also requires some things from CustomApplication class . But as the android native module is a library module (application tag is neglected in library module) I am not able to provide some things to Mainactivity class causing NullPointerException.

Solution could be: 
Not keeping any application class and provide it through some other manner . 
But I have no much idea about library development . Suggest me the best idea to achieve this scenario.